# Clean install of Windows on new m.2 SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, operating-systems

My laptop has HDD of 1 TB which I have partitioned into two drives Local disk C and D of 478 GB (179 GB free) and 353 GB (164 GB free) respectively. Also about 100 GB is partitioned for Ubuntu (dual boot). C contains the OS and program files which I use D for data storage. After installing new SSD I have got a New Volume (E:) of 232 GB. I installed EaseUS Partition Manager which has the option of migrating OS without reinstalling, but when I select E as target disk it shows size is small. I thought it would only migrate the OS which should not take more than 50 GB. Can someone explain if it was trying to clone the whole HDD in the SSD? I want to clean install Windows on the SSD without losing Ubuntu and any of my files on D drive. Can someone recommend me some video or link which can guide me? I found some videos, but I think my situation is different with dual boot.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Answer (score 1):

To my experience, separating "only the OS" is not an easy task with Windows.

As it is complicated enough, I think that EASEUS tries to copy the whole system partition and reconfigure the OS to start from the copy.

I would try to move as many data as possible from C to D, shrink C to max 232 GB and then let EASEUS do its job. Then you can remove the old and create a new C Partition.

Please be prepared that Windows always will call the partition it starts from drive C:, so the drive letters will change.

Comment: Now I want to clean install , can you help me

Comment: Your heading and your content of the question just don't match - What final configuration is your goal? (Might be worth a separate question, or maybe somebody else got answered "how to clean install windows" yet?)